# MySQL Error Code 1215: “Cannot add foreign key constraint”

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I keep getting this error when attempting to create a table with SQL.

I have these two tables:

I'm using PHPMyAdmin and it won't allow me to use M_id as a foreign key which references Employee Table primary key E_id.

Anyone able to see what's wrong with my code?

Thanks!

Comment: keys need to be identical on both tables. Are both tables the same type - InnoDb? Also check that both `INT` columns are the same length

Comment: You are referencing to the same table. ‘FOREIGN KEY (Super_id) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(E_id)’.. this should be another (a foreign) table

Comment: You have a foreign key in employee which references department AND a foreign key in department which references employee - this is not going to work since the referenced table needs to exist before you create the referring table. If you really want to do that create the tables without the FKs and use ALTER statements to add the FKs

Answer (score 3):

Foreign key definitions have to exactly match the primary key columns to which they refer.  In this case, you defined `Department.M_id` to a be a nullable integer column, while `EMPLOYEE.E_id` is integer not nullable.  Try making `M_id` not nullable:

```
CREATE TABLE Department (
    D_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    D_id INT NOT NULL,
    M_id INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0000,
    ...
    FOREIGN KEY (M_id) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(E_id)
    ON DELETE SET DEFAULT   ON UPDATE CASCADE
)
```

Comment: This is not a problem and a quite valid design. Why elese would we have `ON DELETE SET NULL`?

Answer (score 0):

Your code has multiple errors:

- `varchar()` length is too long.
- You have a forward reference for a foreign key constraint.
- `SET DEFAULT` doesn't really work.

You want something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE employees (
  employee_id int not null primary key,
  Job_type VARCHAR(100),
  Ssn INT NOT NULL,
  Salary DECIMAL NOT NULL,
  Address VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
  First_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  M_initial CHAR(1),
  Last_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  E_end_date DATE,
  E_start_date DATE NOT NULL,
  department_id INT NOT NULL,
  Super_id INT,
  FOREIGN KEY (Super_id) REFERENCES employees(employee_id) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  UNIQUE (Ssn)
);

CREATE TABLE departments (
  department_id int primary key,
  D_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  D_id INT NOT NULL,
  M_id INT DEFAULT 0000,
  Manager_start_date DATE NOT NULL,
  Manager_end_date DATE,
  Report VARCHAR(8000),
  Num_of_employees INT NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (M_id) REFERENCES employees(employee_id) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  UNIQUE (D_name)
);

ALTER TABLE employees ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (department_id) REFERENCES departments(department_id)
  ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

I also changed a few other things:

- The table names are plural.
- The primary keys are the singular form followed by "_id".
- Foreign keys and primary keys have the same name.
- The primary key is the first column in the table.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fe2ca0f4c226e09360612c5fda3922c8) is a db<>fiddle showing that this works.

Answer (score 0):

I will not question your design, though it looks problematic.

However - You cannot reference a table which doesn't exist yet (`REFERENCES Department(D_id)`). You should either remove the FOREIGN KEY constraints from the CREATE statements and add them afterwards in ALTER TABLE statements.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE (...);
CREATE TABLE Department (...);

ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEE 
  ADD FOREIGN KEY (D_id)
  REFERENCES Department(D_id)
  ON DELETE CASCADE
  ON UPDATE CASCADE
;
```

[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/p6dEPSEiG6Tj4U7gAPGuXq/0)

Or temporarily disable foreign key checks:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;

CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE (...);

CREATE TABLE Department (...);

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2cqv2uTFhoXyZaWZRVmbxg/0)

You can also not use `ON DELETE SET DEFAULT`. InnoDB doesn't support it. You need to change it to `ON DELETE SET NULL`. If you want that behavior, you will need to implement it either in your application code or in a trigger.

I would also use `TEXT` as data type instead of `VARCHAR(30000)`.